# Android: "Recursive" IntentService?

Tags: android, alarm, schedule, intentservice

Is is the right method to fire up an IntentService? I make a recursive call, because I need to change the alarm ticks.

```
public class AlarmIntentService extends IntentService{
   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
      SharedPreferences spf = getSharedPreferences("PREF_SOMETHING", MODE_PRIVATE);

      intent = new Intent(this, AlarmIntentService.class);
      PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
      AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + spf.getInt("TIME", 1) * 10000, pIntent);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is OK. The only one threat I see is possibility of accidentally run more than one separate "threads".